# products became "out of stock" after update from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0

Tags: magento-2.1

After updating from 2.0.7 to 2.1.0 all the products in catalog became "out of stock". That's how they displaying in my bestseller widget (pic.1).

But in admin panel they always have positive quantity (pic.2), so they have to be "in stock".

And, of course, they are invisible at frontend catalog (pic.3).

Why is that so and how to fix that?

UPD: Only when I'm adding a new product it appears at catalog, but no changes with already existed catalog products.

Pic.1

[image]

Pic.2

[image]

Pic.3

[image]

Comment: Did you try to reindex ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, just did so. Button "add to cart" appeared, but in catalog nothing appeared.  And nothing happened when I tried add product from bestsellers to cart.